# Determine direction of change in array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Given a sorted array, eg. `[1,2,3,4,5]` and a variation of this array, where one of the items got moved to a different position (so no longer sorted) eg. `[1,2,5,3,4]` or `[2,3,4,1,5]` I need to reliably determine the "direction" of the move - left or right depending on which way that one element got moved

(`5` got moved `left` in first example, `1` got moved `right` in a second example)

At the moment I have a solution that walks (from the left) over arrays and compares their values at index `i`  - as soon as they are not the same (to determine point of discrepancy), it then compares values at `i+1`. if `old[i+1] > new[i+1] then left, otherwise right`

```
//pseudocode:
function(old, now) {
  for(var i in old) {
    if (old[i] !== now[i]) {
      return old[i+1] > now[i+1] ? "left" : "right"
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
is there a more reliable (and potentially more efficient) solution to that problem? at the moment it gives "false positives" in certain situations. Do we event need the first array? its always sorted and sequential.

Comment: How much more efficient should it be? O(1)?

Comment: An alternative is to loop over one array and use [*indexOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14) on the other, but I don't know if that's faster or not.

Comment: I don't think you can do better because your method will detect a discrepancy without needing to loop through the entire array.  It seems like in this case you don't have any advantage of loading the data into a binary search tree or a hash table.  

@RobG indexOf isn't optimized and will act like an inner loop where as his current method of going right to the index of the array element is fast.

one last point: Given this array, which value was moved?[1,2,3,5,4,6].
If the move was only one space, you cannot know which was moved.  Is this a problem?

Comment: @WilliamNewby—but *indexOf* will use platform native code, so a very fast loop. *for..in* will proceed in no particular order (which probably doesn't matter because the value that moves might be anywhere) and the OP needs to add an *ownProperty* test or change to a *for* loop (or run the risk of failing in hosts with polyfills on *Array.prototype*).

Comment: @RobG Ah, yes, I forgot that he had a for..in there. The for loop I thought he had would be better and he wouldn't be searching the other array but just comparing at each index until the discrepancy.

Comment: "At the moment I have a solution that walks (from the left)" you don't know that. The order of enumeration using *for..in* is implementation dependent. It will also visit inherited properties. If you want guaranteed iteration from 0 over own properties, use a *for* loop and counter.

Comment: @RobG Granted, it is marked as "pseudocode" :)

Comment: @Jack—yes, but written as real code. :-(

Answer (score 1):

There is not really any room for improvements in your solution - You won't find a way to solve your problem without going trough all members of the array and checking them against the member in the other array.

Your current time complexity is *O(n)*, which is actually not too bad. Therefore you should not worry about this function and if your application is working too slow, you should look for other fields to improve on.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, more discussion of the algorithm.

If you want guaranteed iteration from 0 and to ignore inherited enumerable properties, replace *for..in* with a *for*, *while* or *do* loop.

Given iteration from index 0, the algorigthm you have doesn't work. e.g. in the following:

```
var old = [1,2,3];
var now = [2,1,3];
```

value 1 has been moved right. The algorithm will find a miss-match at index 0, then compare the values at index 1. `old[1]` is greater than `now[1]` so "left" is returned.

It's also impossible to determine the direction of some moves, e.g. in the above was 1 moved right or 2 moved left? Another example:

```
var old = [1,2,3,4,5];
var new = [1,2,3,5,4];
```

Did 4 move right or 5 move left? A rule is required to determine which takes precidence.